# Alert on empty fetch

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I´m trying to make fetch stop and alert if it returns that errorMessage,
so the `()=>this.toggleModal()` wont get executed.

```
    handleSubmit(event){
        const url = 'http://localhost:8000/issue/';
        var issueid = 13900;
        var issueid = document.getElementById("SearchTxt").value;
        if(issueid == 0){
            alert('Please insert IssueID or IssueKey')
        }else{
            var string2 = url+issueid;
            fetch(string2)
            .then(function(response) {
              return response.json();
            })
            .then((myJson) => this.setState({example: myJson},() => this.toggleModal()))
        }
}
```

JSON returned when issue doesn´t exist:

```js
{
    errorMessages: [
        "Issue Does Not Exist"
     ],
     errors: { },
}
```

Comment: what is the issue?

Comment: Do you still want to have your component state updated with `myJson` ? Or completely skip that part ?

Comment: Do you want to execute `.then((myJson) => this.setState({example: myJson}` even though you get your `errorMessage` or do you want to cancel execution after `response.json()` if it contains this message?

Comment: I want to cancel execution, and show the errorMessages on a alert!

Comment: @Eddo no, if that errorMessages comes i don´t need to be updated, just an alert with the message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I´ve managed to fix it:

```js
     handleSubmit(event){
        const url = 'http://localhost:8000/issue/';
        var issueid = 13900;
        var issueid = document.getElementById("SearchTxt").value;
        if(issueid == 0){
            alert('Please insert IssueID or IssueKey')
        }else{
            var string2 = url+issueid;
            fetch(string2)
            .then(function(response) {
              return response.json();
            })
            .then((myJson) => this.conditionalChaining(myJson));
        }
}

conditionalChaining(myJson) {
    if (myJson.errorMessages == 'Issue Does Not Exist') {
        alert('Issue doesn´t exist')
    } else {
        this.setState({example: myJson},() => this.toggleModal());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In case you want to cancel execution at `return response.json();` you could do the following

```
handleSubmit(event){
    const url = 'http://localhost:8000/issue/';
    var issueid = document.getElementById("SearchTxt").value;
    if(issueid == 0 || issueid == "" || issueid == undefined || issueid == null){
        alert('Please insert IssueID or IssueKey')
        return;
    }
    var string2 = url+issueid;
    fetch(string2)
        .then(function(response) {
          const oJson = response.json();
          // your validation of the json
          if(oJson.hasOwnProperty("errorMessages") && oJson.errorMessages.includes("Issue Does Not Exist")
              return Promise.reject(oJson.errorMessages[0]); // maybe use a better way instead of this hardcoded index 

          // set state if everything was properly done
          this.setState({example: myJson},() => this.toggleModal())
        })
        .catch(error => {
            // do some alert stuff
            alert(error);
        });
}
```

Comment: Thanks @r3dst0rm, but toogleModal, still gets executed!

Comment: Thats unfortunate, please try `return Promise.reject(oJson.errorMessages[0]` instead of `throw ...`

Comment: The pop up opens without problems, but it keeps trying to setState!